# Using 4 boards to fill a gap

Tags: wood

I’m stuck with two box springs that are 90cm wide, 200cm long. I need them to fully support a mattress that is 190cm wide, 200cm long. My thought is to attach two 1.8 cm wide, 200 cm long boards to each box spring. My question is what’s the best way. I could somehow attach all 4 boards together and place them between the box springs. I have a board underneath that can support all that, even if they aren’t attached. Another way is to attach two boards to each box spring. For aesthetic reasons, I would attach all the boards on the inside, not one each on each side. The question is how - glue? Bolt and nut? Another idea is a way I haven’t thought of but you have.
With the tools I have, the first two ideas are the most workable.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think we'll need to see a sketch of what you have in mind.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Your Question has attracted downvotes because we can't visualise your proposed plan and/or the requirement from the verbal description; speaking for myself while I can see you have two bases and a mattress that will span them I can't see how the four full-length boards will be the solution. So as @jdv says please provide at least a sketch of your idea so we can get a proper understanding of your plan — it doesn't have to be elaborate, just a back-of-envelope sketch should be sufficient :-)

Comment: For anyone not familiar with a box spring, a modern one is similar to a pallet in structure, wrapped in fabric, and often does not contain actual springs. You put it under a mattress on some types of beds to provide a foundation for the mattress and raise it up. King beds typically use a 2-piece box spring (each piece the size of a Twin XL mattress). I'm not certain why these two box springs are only 90cm, but they may have been salvaged from a King-sized bed for an RV, which is 10 cm narrower than a standard king.
https://gottasleep.com/pages/mattress-sizes-dimensions

Answer (score 1):

> My thought is to attach two 1.8 cm wide, 200 cm long boards to each box spring. My question is what’s the best way.

Forget trying to attach boards to the box springs. Just buy a sheet of 1/2" or 3/4" plywood and lay it on top of the box springs, with a 10 cm gap between the box springs. The weight of the mattress will hold the plywood in place, but if you're worried about it a few screws through the plywood into the box springs will lock everything in place. If you lack the tools to cut the plywood to size, any home center will be happy to cut it for you.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand what 'box spring' is, won't this cover springs? Also 8x4 = 1220 x 2440, 2 sheets needed I think.

Comment: @VolframK a modern box spring is a similar to a pallet in structure, and often does not have actual metal springs. You put it under a mattress on some types of beds to provide a support foundation for the mattress and raise it up from the bed frame.

Comment: @rob thank you.